# Read a file and extract data and assign to a variable from a python file

Tags: python, scons, conan

I am trying to extract BINPATH, LIBPATH,CPPPATH from a conan.txt file which looks like:

```
conan = {

    "conan" : {
        "CPPPATH"     : ['something'],
        "BINPATH"     : ['something'],
        "LIBS"        : ['something'],
        "CPPDEFINES"  : [],
        "CXXFLAGS"    : [],
        "CCFLAGS"     : [],
        "SHLINKFLAGS" : [],
        "LINKFLAGS"   : [],
    },
    "conan_version" : "None",

    "boost" : {
        "CPPPATH"     : ['C:\\.conan\\123456\\1\\include'],
        "LIBPATH"     : ['C:\\.conan\\123456\\1\\lib'],
        "BINPATH"     : ['C:\\.conan\\123456\\1\\lib'],
        "LIBS"        : [],
        "CPPDEFINES"  : [],
        "CXXFLAGS"    : [],
        "CCFLAGS"     : [],
        "SHLINKFLAGS" : [],
        "LINKFLAGS"   : [],
    },
    "boost_version" : "1.69.0"
}
Return('conan')
```

I have a scons /python file which needs CPPPATH,BINPATH,LIBPATH values as variable.
I am trying to extract these values in following function in Sconscript :

```
def getCPPPath():
          data = {'Return': lambda x: False}
            with open(file.txt, 'r') as f:
             exec(f.read(), data)
             return (data["conan"]["conan"]["CPPPATH"][0])
             print ("Path is:", ["conan"]["conan"]["CPPPATH"][0])
```

This gives me an error:

```
scons: *** Return of non-existent variable ''conan''
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Isn't conan a dict or json?

Comment: Looks like a valid python code. You can use `exec(f.read(), myvar)` then get the value as `myvar['conan']['boost']['BINPATH']` etc

Comment: @Ch3steR, I used scons generator in recipe file to generate this text file

Comment: @hurlenko : my code return this error:Traceback (most recent call last): File "testfile3.py", line 3, in <module> exec(f.read(), data) File "<string>", line 83, in <module> NameError: name 'Return' is not defined

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following code. Note that [exec](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) is insecure as it runs all the code that is in your `file.txt`. You also need to pass a dummy `Return` function into `exec`.

```py
data = {"Return": lambda x: False}

with open("file.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    exec(f.read(), data)

print(data['conan']['conan']['BINPATH'][0])
print(data['conan']['boost']['LIBPATH'][0])
print(data['conan']['conan']['CPPPATH'][0])
```

Prints

```py
['something']
['C:\\.conan\\123456\\1\\lib']
['something']
```

Comment: my code return this error:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testfile3.py", line 3, in <module>
    exec(f.read(), data)
  File "<string>", line 83, in <module>
NameError: name 'Return' is not defined

Comment: Your initial text example didn't have the `Return('conan')` part. I updated the answer

Comment: It works! Thank you.But how do I remove those square brackets since it prints like below:['C:\\.conan\\86ed06\\1\\include']
['C:\\.conan\\86ed06\\1\\lib']
['C:\\.conan\\86ed06\\1\\lib']

Comment: Those are lists, just use the first element. I updated the answer

Comment: Awesome. Can you tell you what does data = {"Return": lambda x: False} mean

Comment: You can execute code from `file.txt` in local scope by omitting the `data` argument to `exec`. Instead you can pass local and global scopes for execution. I defined global scope with a single function `Return` so that the code from `file.txt` could use it.

Comment: How Can I extract data from file..txt as a Sconscript (build script) in my python file ?

Comment: edited my question further for your reference please, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A lot easier and w/o using exec.
You need to name your file `conan.py` (<= note the .py ending):

```
import conan

data = conan.conan
print(data['conan']['BINPATH'])

=> ['something']
```

Comment: I don't understand what you have in foo.py

Comment: This works for your 1st version without the return("conan") in the last line.

Comment: Let me know whether you need the return statement or why did you add it?
If it stays I will delete my answer as it does not comply with your recent change.

Comment: return is required since this file was created by conan generator module itself. BTW, @hurlenko's code worked, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're trying to set up Conan with SCons, there's another way. If this was "normal" Python, the two other answers would've been completely correct. However, since you're clearly using the SCons generator in Conan (otherwise, you wouldn't have ended up with that file), you have a file that's compatible with SCons. SCons naturally has additions on top of Python for managing its "own" files.

Therefore, you don't need exec at all. this is all you need:

```py
conan = env.SConscript("SConscript_conan")
# Note: you may need to change the path to SConscript_conan depending on your 
#       build system configuration. If you installed Conan in `build`, the
#       path should be "build/SConscript_conan"
env.MergeFlags(conan["conan"])
```

This also ensures you add all the other flags you need, not just the paths. Also saves you manual setup if you ever decide to add another library.

`Return('conan')` is an SCons function, which basically is equivalent to returning a variable (here: `conan`) from an SConscript file into whatever executed it. Incorrect execution, or of course the lacking existence of a variable, is enough to cause the function to throw. If you source the SConscript file properly, it should work as expected.

See also the [Conan documentation](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/integrations/build_system/scons.html), specifically the second code snippet, and [the SCons docs on SConscript files](https://scons.org/doc/4.0.1/HTML/scons-user.html#idp140430748480840)